# Find all nodes with specific labels aren't connected

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to find all nodes of specified type that aren't connected?

Lets say I have nodes with Labels like :UserOrder and :OrderPayment. Paid orders are typically connected like: `(user:UserOrder)-[r:PROCESSED {date:xxxxx}]->(order:OrderPayment)`

In hypothetical scenario in some cases due to some errors payments aren't processes and as a result are not connected with orders. How would I find all UsersOrders and OrderPayments that aren't connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the fastest way:

```
MATCH n
WHERE (n:UsersOrder OR n:OrderPayment) AND NOT (n)--()
RETURN n;
```

Comment: It's convenient to do both in one query, but that means you're not getting the nodes by their labels, but have to first bind all nodes and then test for label, which can be expensive.

Comment: @jjaderberg agreed, making it two separate queries is probably a lot faster

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on the absence of a relationship in the `WHERE` clause. If you want to exclude the UserOrder nodes that have any relation whatsoever you can do

```
MATCH (user:UserOrder)
WHERE NOT (user)--()
RETURN user
```